# Do horse armor enchantments have an effect?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Using command blocks or NBT-edit (or even enchanted books in creative I think), you can create horse armor with enchantments.

Do enchantments like *Protection* or even *Sharpness* have an effect when the armor is equipped on the horse? So will the *Protection* enchantment actually protect the horse from taking damage?

It would be great to have these features for a PVP map.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [Minecraft wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Horse_Armor):

> Horse armor cannot be enchanted in survival mode, but you can use an anvil in creative mode. Enchanted horse armor will not have any effects on the horse.

So no, **enchantments to horse armor will not have any affect on a horse.** In addition, the armor will not "glow" as if it was enchanted.

Answer (score -1):

When you enchant horse armor on console(Xbox 360 edition) it glows in inventory but does not glow when on a horse. Protection does not work but unbreaking does!
Based on personal experience.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! Please see [this page](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/promotion) describing what self-promotion is allowed on this site. Otherwise, this answer (and your account) may be deleted if you continue linking to your youtube.